# #apify Looking to filter jobs on click to a filter check box

Tags: apify

I have created a actor.

Starts URL: https://www.klinikum-nf.de/karriere/aktuelle-stellenangebote

I am simply able to crawl the jobs but I need to first apply filter by checked the check box and then crawl jobs.

Without filter there 41 jobs and with filter there are 19 jobs are there.

Actually I need 19 jobs not 41.

I used a click triger function but it din't work and returning 41 jobs.

$( document ).ready(function() {$('#fc_id_aerztinnen_-_aerzte').trigger('click');});

Can you please help how this is possible with Apify?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [apify/web-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper), you can simply call 
`$('#fc_id_aerztinnen_-_aerzte').click()`
in your pageFunction it should work. You can add short sleep after the click like to make sure it process:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
   const { jQuery: $, waitFor, saveSnapshot } = context;
   $('#fc_id_aerztinnen_-_aerzte').click();
   await waitFor(1000);
   await saveSnapshot();
}
```